# $scope and $rootScope in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, scope, rootscope

I am working on ionic project , I have 2 views 
first view : The user enter a value (integer number) then click a button to take me to view 2
Second view : Displays to me list of numbers from 1 to the value the user entered

this is my input :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="input a value " ng-model="val">
```

and this is the Ctrl for the view 1

```
.controller('homeCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
$scope.val;
$rootScope.value= $scope.val;
})
```

this is view 2 list

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat='num in list' item="num"> {{num}} 
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

and this is the ctrl

```
.controller('listCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {

var num = $rootScope.value;
$scope.list=[];
  for(var i=1; i<num ; i++)
  {
    $scope.list.push(i);
  }

})
```

the problem is in the first controller , this line

```
$rootScope.value= $scope.val;
```

the $rootScope doesn't take the value of $scope.val 
when  I put a test value like this 
    $rootScope.value= 8;

the list are working, else it doesn't

where are the problem please
I don't have any errors
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning the current value of $scope.val

What you'll need to do is add a $watch to watch for changes to 'val' like so:

```
$scope.$watch('val', function(newval) {
  $rootScope.value = newval;
});
```

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a points-yuppie :), if this answer was correct for you, could you mark it as the answer?